# Optimize Data Sending/Querying to Parse Swift iOS

Tags: performance, swift, mvc, ios, parse-platform

I have a swift method that I'm using to update Parse in the backend when the button is tapped. Votes are being updated: The method acts as a voting system, incrementing a label every time it's tapped. This action is happening in a Custom Cell:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var votesLabel: UILabel!

    var parseObject:PFObject?
   @IBAction func happyBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    if(parseObject != nil) {

        if var votes: Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {

            votes!++
            parseObject!.setObject(votes!, forKey: "votes")
            parseObject!.saveInBackground()

          votesLabel?.text = "+\(votes!)"
            // print(votes)
        }

    }
}
```

Was wondering how I can optimize this function to send the data to and from Parse in the most efficient manner?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Well done on the clean-up :-)

Comment: Thanks @Mast! Any clues as to how to improve this would be greatly appreciated as well :)

Comment: Wouldn't recommend putting the update code inside the function that handles the tap event, not really reusable

Comment: Furthermore, are you noticing performance issues or you just want to optimize for the sake of it? Could consider using saveEventually()

Comment: Currently, this works fine. However, I'm assuming that the sending of data could be done in a more efficient manner than sending to the server every time the user votes. Do you know what I mean? Lastly, I've tried putting this code in the TableViewController in the tap event but it doesn't get executed. @DanielGalasko

Comment: Sounds like you might be prematurely optimising here. If you really wanted to save network you could just have a "sync" button that gives control to the user. But I can't see a valid reason for trying to optimise this path. There are definitely bigger problems to solve?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. However, how complex would it be to integrate the sync? What does it involve?

Comment: Is this different  optimistic programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some feedback concerning the usage of Swift optionals  in 
your code.

The main point is that there is far too much "forced unwrapping". The forced unwrap operator `!` can and should be avoided
in most cases. Instead of comparing with `nil` and forced unwrapping

```
if (parseObject != nil) {
     parseObject!.doSomething()
     parseObject!.doSomethingElse()
}
```

use optional binding to test *and* get the unwrapped value:

```
if let theParseObject = parseObject {
     theParseObject.doSomething()
     theParseObject.doSomethingElse()
}
```

*Or*, if `parseObject` is *expected* to be non-nil when the method
is called (e.g. because it is set up in `viewDidLoad`), declare it
as an implicitly unwrapped optional

```
var parseObject : PFObject!
// ...
parseObject.doSomething()
parseObject.doSomethingElse()
```

There is no reason to declare `var notes` as an optional `Int?`.
With

```
if var votes = parseObject.objectForKey("votes") as? Int { ... }
```

you get rid of more forced unwrap operators.

Finally, the `votesLabel` textfield outlet is expected to be non-nil
(otherwise you did not connect it correctly in the interface builder).
That is the reason why it is declared as an implicitly unwrapped optional
`UILabel!`. There is no need for optional chaining in

```
 votesLabel?.text = "+\(votes!)"
```

Putting it all together, the method should look like this:

```
@IBAction func happyBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let theParseObject = self.parseObject {
        if var votes = theParseObject.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
            votes++
            theParseObject.setObject(votes, forKey: "votes")
            theParseObject.saveInBackground()
            votesLabel.text = "+\(votes)"
        }
    }
}
```

No `!` anymore!

Comment: hey this works, thanks a lot! Why is forced unwrapping bad practice in this case? Why is it bad practice in general? Does this increase speed, execution? Overall question: what does this change do compiler wise? Thank you once again.

Comment: @lukesIvi: Each `x!` is a possible candidate for a runtime crash. It relies on *you* doing the appropriate checks before. Doing "test and unwrap" once saves some instructions later and is safer. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717210/when-should-i-compare-an-optional-value-to-nil.